# What is the group of endomorphisms of $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: group-theory

As the question says, I'm trying to work out what $End_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$ is. These are just group homomorphisms. But so far all I can see is that its probably enough to see where elements of the form $1/n$ map to, but some hints would be helpful

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decompose $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ into primary components: define $t_p(G)=\{g\in G: p^ng=0\text{ for some }n>0\}$ where $p$ is a prime and $G$ is an additive abelian group; then $G=\bigoplus_p t_p(G)$.

What can you say about $f\colon t_p(G)\to t_q(G)$ when $p\ne q$? What's $\operatorname{End}(t_p(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}))$?

Comment: Well I think when $p \neq q$ then there can't be any non-trivial homomorphisms $t_p(G)$ to $t_q(G)$ because $q^nf(g)=f(q^ng)=0$ but $q^ng$ doesnt have to be zero in $t_p$. Now as for $End(t_p(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$ I'm not quite sure I can see that any $1/p^n$ has to map to some $1/p^m$ with $m<n$ I think

Comment: Ok so I think I can prove that $End(t_p(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}))$ is $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, so then would that mean that $End(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$ is isomorphic to $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$

Comment: @user39947 Not $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, but the ring of $p$-adic integers; actually you seem to know it, because usually $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$ denotes the product of all the rings of $p$-adic integers. You're correct in deducing that an endomorphism maps each primary component into itself, so the endomorphism ring is just the product of the endomorphism rings of the primary components.

Answer (score 2):

By definition,
$$
\operatorname{End}_\Bbb{Z}(\Bbb{Q}/\Bbb{Z}) = \operatorname{Hom}_\Bbb{Z}(\Bbb{Q}/\Bbb{Z}, \Bbb{Q}/\Bbb{Z}),
$$
and order to define such a map, it is equivalent to think of a map
$$
f \in \operatorname{Hom}_\Bbb{Z}(\Bbb{Q}, \Bbb{Q}/\Bbb{Z})
$$
such that
$$
\Bbb{Z} \subseteq \ker f.
$$
Hint:  think about $f\left( \frac{1}{n} \right)$, for $n \in \Bbb{Z}$.

Comment: I realize that you likely know everything that I just wrote.  Additionally, my hint is essentially confirming your suspicion.  But, you seem to be trying to solve this problem *yourself,* so I'm not just writing down a solution.